# kivy multicolor ListView

Tags: python, listview, colors, kivy

i want to define unique color for all element in listview

actually i create list view like this :

```
from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton, ListView

data = ["blue","green","yellow","black","white"]

list_adapter = ListAdapter(data=data,
                           args_converter=args_converter,
                           cls=ListItemButton,
                           selection_mode='single',
                           allow_empty_selection=False)

list_view = ListView(adapter=list_adapter)
```

all elements have green background i want multicolor listview, i want that  blue item have blue background, black item have black background...etc.

it's possible ?
thanks for advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `args_converter`, and pass the data in a list of dictionaries:

```
from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton, ListView

data = [{"text": "blue", "color": (0, 0, 1, 1)},
        {"text": "green", "color": (0, 1, 0, 1)}, 
        {"text":"yellow", "color": (1, 1, 0, 1)}, 
        {"text": "black", "color": (0, 0, 0, 1)}, 
        {"text": "white", "color": (1, 1, 1, 1)}]

args_converter = lambda row_index, rec: {'text': rec['text'],
                                         'deselected_color': rec['color'],
                                         'selected_color': rec['color'],
                                         'size_hint_y': None,
                                         'height': 25}

list_adapter = ListAdapter(data=data,
                           args_converter=args_converter,
                           cls=ListItemButton,
                           selection_mode='single',
                           allow_empty_selection=False)

list_view = ListView(adapter=list_adapter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp
    runTouchApp(list_view)
```

[image]